# Оптимизация jQuery кода

Tags: jquery, инспекция-кода

Сточки зрения оптимизации/качества jQuery кода, мог бы кто-то подсказать основные правила?

Например, вот мой первый скрипт:

```
$(function(){
    $block = $('#menu');
    $blockPosition = $block.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $windowPosition = $window.scrollTop();
        if ($windowPosition > $blockPosition) {
            $block.addClass('fix');
        }else{
            $block.removeClass('fix');
        }
    });
});
```

Какие замечания могут быть по этому коду, спасибо.

Comment: добавьте `var` перед `$block`, `$blockPosition` и `$windowPosition`, чтобы сделать их локальными переменными

Comment: Это, вобщемто, нормально использовать `$` в названиях всех переменных, но обычно ожидается что такая переменная будет сожержать какойнить особый объект (jquery, zepto ...), `$blockPosition` и  `$windowPosition` содержат обычные `int`.

Comment: @Igor var $block или var block и в чем разница?

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев - "Переменные, начинающиеся со знака $ - глобальные" - можно ссылку на источник?

Comment: @Igor, вы правы - мое заявление про глобальность переменных с `$` в начале - в корне неверное. `$` не влияет на глобальность переменной никоим образом, как и не влияет вообще ни на что. Извиняюсь, что своим комментарием ввел в заблуждение.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, долларом в начале принято помечать переменные с объектами jQuery, чтоб удобнее было в коде разбираться

Comment: А вообще - такой код можно (и, я считаю, нужно) написать без всяких jQuery

Comment: @andreymal, скорее, вообще без скриптов :)

Comment: @andreymal ну и как написать в таком случаи без скрипта? http://SSMaker.ru/857b8339/

Comment: @РодионПоляков не отображается скриншот, даже с отключенным адблоком. И «без jQuery» и «без скриптов» — вещи разные, я утверждаю первое, но не второе

Comment: Перепутал, мой вопрос был адресован @Qwertiy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> $block = $('#menu');
> ```

Переменные надо объявлять через `var`, чтобы они не становились глобальными:

```
 var $block = $('#menu');
```

> ```
> $blockPosition = $block.offset().top;
> ```

При написании кода на jQuery со знака доллара обычно начинают имена переменных, содержащих jQuery-наборы, поэтому просто

```
var blockPosition = $block.offset().top;
```

> ```
> if ($windowPosition > $blockPosition) {
>     $block.addClass('fix');
> }else{
>     $block.removeClass('fix');
> }
> ```

Есть замечательный второй параметр у функции [toggleClass](//api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), только он обязан быть boolean:

```
$block.toggleClass('fix', $windowPosition > $blockPosition);
```

> ```
> $windowPosition
> ```

Переменные, используемые один раз, часто можно не заводить:

```
$block.toggleClass('fix', $window.scrollTop() > $blockPosition);
```

> $window

Эта переменная нигде не объявлялась...

> Скажите пожалуйста, если $(window) используется в коде больше одного раза, его нужно кэшировать в переменой и являться window jQuery-набором?

С ним стоит поступать так же, как со всеми другими переменными.

Вообще, моё мнение, что если нечто запрашивается один раз *за время обработки события*, то кэшировать не нужно. Это позволяет получить актуальные элементы, избежать загромождения кода лишними переменными и потенциального удерживания неиспользуемых dom-элементов в памяти. К тому же, некоторые события могут и не возникнуть, а при изначальном кэшировании мы делаем уйму лишних поисков.

Но есть и другое мнение - сразу кэшировать всё что нужно.

> ```
> }else{
> ```

Около скобок принято ставить пробелы

```
} else {
```

---

Итоговый код:

```
$(function () {
  var $block = $('#menu');
  var blockPosition = $block.offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    $block.toggleClass('fix', $(window).scrollTop() > blockPosition);
  });
});
```

Хотя, честно говоря, у меня вызывает сомнение получение положения блока сразу после загрузки документа. Оно точно должно быть именно там?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, если $(window) используется в коде больше одного раза, его нужно кэшировать в переменой и являться window jQuery-набором?

Comment: @РодионПоляков, ответ дополнен.

Comment: `$(window)` все-таки стоит кэшировать. Причина проста: событие `scroll` может вызываться с большой частотой. Аргументы _против_ видел, в данном случаи они не существенны.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в целом про скролл согласен, но `var t=performance.now(); for(var q=0; q<1000000; ++q) $(window); console.log(performance.now()-t);` выполняется в моём хроме менее чем за 9 секунд - миллион оборачиваний за 9 секунд - т. е. можно выполнить более 1000 таких операций за keyframe (16 ms).

Comment: Ключевые слова "_в моём хроме_". Раз уж вопрос про [tag:инспекция-кода], то надо доводить инспекцию до конца.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в IE11 - меньше 12 секунд.

Comment: @Qwertiy, раз начали оптимизировать - нужно доводить до конца. Тесты на "_моем хроме/IE_" считаю нерелевантными. Ну и от меня минус, за непоследовательность в деле оптимизации.

Comment: @Qwertiy - http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-state можете пояснить?

Comment: @РодионПоляков, если второй параметр true, то класс добавляется, а если false, то убирается. Ну нужно именно true/false, а не любые истинные или ложные значения.

Comment: @Qwertiy мне не понятно что именно не желательно в JQuery 3.0 из toggleClass.

Comment: @РодионПоляков, а я не говорил про jQuery 3. Оно вообще тут нигде не упоминалось. UPDATE: а, нонял. Это вариант без имени класса.

Answer (score 1):

В плане оптимизации я думаю имеет место называть переменные своими именами а не `block`. Не плодить одноразовые переменные вроде `$windowPosition`. Не использовать `$` в переменных, честно говоря я не знаю куда они попадают, но это явно не хорошо.

```
$(function(){
    var menu = $('#menu'),
        menuOffset = menu.offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > menuOffset) {
            menu.addClass('fix');
        } else {
            menu.removeClass('fix');
        }
    }).trigger('scroll');
});
```

Также поправил ошибку которую сам ловил - если прокрутить и остановить страницу до того, как инициализируется jquery, меню не прилипнет, поэтому его надо пнуть на всякий случай.

Answer (score 1):

Главное правило поддерживать одикаковый стиль программирования "code conventions"
Переменные называть по ихнему действию.
Jquery конструкции можно удлинять в строку.
К примеру:

```
$('div').append(table.filter('[data-clone]').clone().removeAttr('data-clone').show());
```

И так далее. Это прийдёт с опытом...
Главное двигаться в правильном направлении.

```js
$(function(){
    $block = $('#menu');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      console.log($(this).scrollTop());
      ($(this).scrollTop() > $block.offset().top) ?
        $block.addClass('fix') :
      $block.removeClass('fix');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Можно добавить. Если сделать так:

```
$block = $('#menu');  
$block.remove(); 
console.log($block);
```

// 1 обьект из памяти. В DOM его нет. Тоесть Значение переменной не действительное.

Comment: 1. А `$block.offset().top`  не меняется? 2. `toggleClass`.

Comment: Вы поломали логику, тут скрипт получает оффсет меню изначально. Да и шортхенд с таким количеством символов превращается в непонятную лапшу, особенно начинающему вообще не понятно визуально. Если так хочется укоротить то можно использовать сборщики.

Comment: По быстрому накидал. Не тестировал.

Comment: А $block.offset().top не меняется? Нет от не меняеться!